# Erdos (1970) proof of Turan's Theorem - Applying induction on S

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, extremal-graph-theory

I am following "[Turan's Graph Theorem](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7E2014-15/1term/ma121a/Aigner%20-%20Turans%20Graph%20Theorem.pdf)" by M. Aigner. In the second proof by Erdos, he states,

> "Applying induction on S, we thus infer that among the graphs with a maximal number of edges there is a graph $K_{n_1,...,n_{k-1}}$"

is where I get confused with the proof. What does he mean by induction on S? I feel as I need help with the steps between the construction of H, how it gives the upperbound for edges of G (i.e $|E(H)|\geq|E(G)|$) , and how by "induction on S" we know there's a Turan graph among the graphs with maximal edges (also, does this imply that graph H *is* that Turan graph-if so, what guarantees it?).

Thank you

Comment: For other readers: He cites page 3, "Second proof (Erdös 1970)" second paragraph last sentence.

Comment: The Turan graph is indeed the (unique) extremal graph of a clique, this can be proven by induction  the same way it is proven for the case of a triangle (see Mantel's theorem above Erdos proof).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "Applying induction on $S$" means "Applying the $k-1$ case of the theorem to the subgraph $G[S]$".

Formally, the theorem we're proving here is the following version of Turán's theorem:

> **Theorem.** For all $n,k$, if $G$ is an $n$-vertex graph with no $k$-clique, then there is a $(k-1)$-partite $n$-vertex graph with at least as many edges as $G$.

Going through all the things you want help with:

**The construction of $H$.** We let $m$ be a vertex in $G$ with the largest degree; $S$ is the set of neighbors of $m$, and $T$ is the complement of $S$ (so $m \in T$). To get $H$ from $G$, we:

- Delete all edges within $T$ (if there were any);
- Add all missing edges between $S$ and $T$ (if there were any).

**Why is $|E(H)| \ge |E(G)|$?** We prove a stronger statement: for all vertices $v$, $\deg_H(v) \ge \deg_G(v)$. This gives us an inequality between the edge counts, since the sum of degrees gives us twice the number of edges.

We check the degree inequality separately in two cases:

- Suppose $v \in S$. In this case, going from $G$ to $H$, we did not delete any edges out of $v$, but possibly we added some edges (if $v$ was not already adjacent to all of $T$). So we can only increase the degree of $v$.
- Suppose $v \in T$. In this case, the degree of $v$ in $H$ is $|S|$, since $H$ contains all edges between $S$ and $T$. In $G$, the degree of $v$ was at most the degree of $m$ (by our choice of $m$), so it was at mot $|S|$.

**How does the induction work?** It is an induction on $k$. The base case can be $k=2$: the only graph with no $2$-cliques (edges) is the empty graph, which is a $1$-partite graph.

If $G$ started out as a graph with no $k$-cliques, then the subgraph $G[S]$ must be a subgraph with no $(k-1)$-cliques (any $(k-1)$-clique in $G[S]$ would form a $k$-clique together with $m$). By induction, there is some $(k-2)$-partite graph $K$ on $|S|$ vertices with $|E(K)| \ge |E(G[S])|$.

Now modify $H$ by replacing $G[S]$ (or $H[S]$, which is the same thing) with the $(k-2)$-partite graph $K$. The result (call it $H'$)

- Still has at least as many edges as $G$: the number of edges did not decrease when going from $G$ to $H$, and it did not decrease when replacing $G[S]$ with $K$.
- Is $(k-1)$-partite. Since $K$ is a $(k-2)$-partite graph on $S$, there is a partition $S = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \dots \cup S_{k-2}$ such that $K$ has no edges inside any $S_i$. Also, $H$ has no edges inside $T$, because we deleted them all. So $H'$ has a vertex partition $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \dots \cup S_{k-2} \cup T$ with no edges inside any part: this is the definition of a $(k-1)$-partite graph.

This proves the theorem.

Comment: Could you explain the last bullet point: "Is (k-1) partite..." part more in detail? I understand that (k-2) partite graph, graph K, is the upper bound for the modified H (i.e. $|E(G)|\le|E(H)|\le|E(S)|\le|E(K)|$). But I don't understand your last bullet point. Also, would going in the direction of $|E(K)|\le(1/2)\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} a_i(n-a_i)$ be any help at all?

Comment: I elaborated on the last bullet point, hopefully that helps.

Comment: It is not true that $|E(H)| \le |E(S)| \le |E(K)|$. Now that I've given the graph in those bullet points a name, we have $|E(G)| \le |E(H)| \le |E(H')|$, but $K$ has many fewer edges, because it does not have the edges between $S$ and $T$. As for the inequality you have, that's not useful for this theorem, because we're not trying to put any numerical bound on $|E(G)|$ yet; we're just proving that $|E(G)| \le |E(H')|$ where $H'$ is a $(k-1)$-partite graph. Once we've done that, then we can ask what the best $(k-1)$-partite graph can do.

Comment: Your elaboration made so much sense, thank you. My apologies on the inequality. My mistake was that I was counting _degrees_ of the vertices belonging to a set rather than _edges_ within the set (i.e. when I said "$|E(S)|$, I was mistakenly calculating the sum of degree of vertices in set S, which adds all the edges going in and out of S to T and edges connecting vertices in S). Thank you very much for your help again.